# Publish Net Core Web API in NAS Synology

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nas

I have a requirement to publish a Net Core Web API on a Synology NAS server. I do not have the faintest idea how to do this. Any help you can give me in this regard?

Comment: For a possible workaround, you may consider installing docker in synology and then hosting .net core web api in docker. Refer [Docker on a Synology NAS - Also running ASP.NET and .NET Core!](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DockerOnASynologyNASAlsoRunningASPNETAndNETCore.aspx)

Comment: Another great example (with a bit clearer details) is found here:  http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Running-ASPNET-Core-Apps-on-a-Synology-NAS-with-Docker

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to contributor [hgy59](https://github.com/hgy59), Dot net runtime is now available in package center - community section.

1. If you don't have community section displayed in package center. Add it from Package Center - Settings - Package sources - Add - http://packages.synocommunity.com/
2. Install Dotnet 6 runtime in "Package center - Community" just like other packages.
3. Publish your Web API or app as Folder, compress the folder and upload to your NAS, and unzip it. Say the unzipped path is /var/services/homes/admin/webapps/SampleAPI
4. Control Panel - Task Scheduler - Create - Triggered Task - User defined script - Ensure Event is "Boot-up". In "Task Settings" - "Run command", type the command which will start your app. E.g.

   /usr/local/bin/dotnet /var/services/homes/admin/webapps/SampleAPI/SampleAPI.dll --urls "http://192.168.50.10:5100" &
5. Click "OK", enable this task, and run the task. Now access the URL you defined above.

Comment: Great, now can I use nginx with it?

Comment: I cant start the app.  i use as  Target Runtme: linux-arm and  Deploiment-Mode: Self-Contain.  Then from the terminal /volume1/web/webApi/My_Api. Some suggestions ?