# Can I host a .Net Framework asp.net Website on Synology NAS

Tags: asp.net, .net, synology, nas

I have written a website in Visual Studio using .Net Framework (4.7.2). (Note: it is not using .net Core)

It is an asp.net website that uses .aspx pages and uses a SQL Server Database on my laptop.

Is it possible to run this website on my Synology NAS and if so would it be able to connect to the database on my laptop (that is on the same network).

Answer (score 2):

.Net framework app can only be run in Windows OS. But Synology is Linux based.

So if you want to run your app in Synology badly, you need to convert it to .Net Core app.

Here is my answer in another question explaining how to run .Net core app in Synology.

[Publish Net Core Web API in NAS Synology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265367/publish-net-core-web-api-in-nas-synology)

Answer (score 0):

You need a full os running windows,  and then you also need sql server installed,  and you also need iis (internet services (the web server)) installed on that server.

So you need a windows os, and preferably a server based version of windows (such as windows server 2019).

Unless that server allows you to install and run windows software? Then no that will not work.