# Publish Net Core Web API in NAS Synology, web root path problem

Tags: asp.net-core, synology

I am trying to use the Synology package ".NET 6.0 runtime" by hgy59 to create a small website. I am using the example of this post :
[Publish Net Core Web API in NAS Synology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265367/publish-net-core-web-api-in-nas-synology/77780821#77780821)

I can't find the github or any repository where I can ask questions so here I am.

I am a bit of a noob regarding ASP.NET. I am usually developing in C# or VB but no web.
But know I need it.

So, the question :
How can I set the working directory to the wwwroot folder of the published app instead of '/usr/syno/synoman/webapi/ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution to my problem bellow so I post it there.
It was indeed a problem with the root directory. To fix it : you need the following lines of codes

```
string basedir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

WebApplicationOptions options = new()
{
  ContentRootPath = basedir,
  Args= args,
  WebRootPath = Path.Combine(basedir, "wwwroot")
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
```

Yes the rootpath need to be set and pass to the builder. I had tried to modify the root path AFTER the creation of the builder but it was ignored and i had given up. But this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=net-6.0) to set the working directory.

**Usage:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// make sure you have permission to access '/usr/syno/synoman/wwwroot/'
var pathToContentRoot = @"F:\\sites\\m3u8";
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
```

*Tips*

When the application terminates, the working directory is restored to its original location (the directory where the process was started).

Comment: I have tried your solution but even if it does change the working dir, "WebApplication".Environment.ContentRootPath or "WebApplication".Environment.WebRootPath are not updated nor the the relative path